# Handle callback from inline keyboard ( telegram bot ) with javascript

Tags: javascript, bots, spreadsheet, telegram

I'm creating this telegram bot as a google app (in a spreadsheet) so I can't use any package for nodejs like Telegraph or Telebot.

What I need to do is that for each inline button pressed the bot will do a specific action. This is the code that displays the keyboard under the message

```
bot.replyToSender("Quello inserito non è un codice utente valido. Il codice utente deve essere un numero!",JSON.stringify({
        "inline_keyboard": [
          [{ "text": "BUTTON_1", url: "SOME_RANDOM_URL_HERE"}], //This button does work, it sends me to the specific url
          [{ "text": "BUTTON_2", "callback_data" :"B"}]
        ]
      }));
```

The problem starts here when I want to do something with BUTTON_2 ( like change the message that generated that callback or just reply back to the user ).

I just can't get anything from the API page of Telegram... Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [similar bot](https://github.com/Rotimi-Best/attendance-bot) that works with a google spreadsheet and updates the spreadsheet after an action is taken, you can check it out. I didn't use the google app in the spreadsheet. In my opinion that approach would be much harder because you can't leverage most available libraries that are available which does most of the hard work for you.

To answer the question you would need to use the method `answercallbackquery` available in the [docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery). I don't know how exactly it would look like using google app but it should look something like this

```
if (query.data === "B") {  // query is an object from the response you get when the user clicks the inline button
  bot.answercallbackquery(query.id, {
     text: `You successfully clicked the button`
  });
}
```

This might not be the same exact implementation for you but the fields are the same for `answerInlineQuery`.

You can check how I implement it [here](https://github.com/Rotimi-Best/mytodos/blob/master/callbackQueries/index.js)

It can be a bit confusing because I used [telegram-node-bot](https://github.com/Naltox/telegram-node-bot) which uses MVC so the inline query needed to be set in my [index.js file](https://github.com/Rotimi-Best/mytodos/blob/4b0ca3435a3685c65d26a172c6c58ca7362b9026/index.js#L12) before I could use the `answercallbackquery` method.

However it works perfectly fine. Feel free to ask further questions.

Cheers )